# How do I retrieve data from a harddisk running Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery

I have removed the harddisk and plugged into another PC running Windows and tried to get the data through but couldn't. Can anyone guide me on how can I get the data, because I cannot get to my lockscreen in Ubuntu

Version 18.04.

Comment: I would `mount` the disk and navigate to where the data you want is, and `cp` it off. This is the same on any OS in my experience, complicated by the *file-systems* in use plus any encryption used, none of which you really specified (no release info, and no *fs* detail at all). How the *lockscreen* applies I don't know as that bit seems different to the prior sentence  (access the data on windows though is off-topic as this isn't a windows support site) https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Ik this isn't a windows support site but as I wan to retrieve data from the harddisk which was running Ubuntu I thought this site would be helpful what all details you need you can ask for it and where do you exactly mean to mount the disk

Comment: Unable to upload pictures form my mobile ill upload it soon

Comment: `mount` is a command which mounts a disk/device into a directory so you can read/write/peruse files in your normal directory structure. You can use `man mount` to read the reference manual page for the `mount` command. As you're using windows though, you'll need to use windows commands, plus you need to know the *file-system* used on your system (Ubuntu can use EXT, XFS, BTRFS, REISERFS, ZFS along with many others selected at install time, and you've provided no details). The `mount` (on windows) will likely need this information (and will need drivers support for some before it can `mount`)

Comment: Sadly I don't know what drives have already been installed and what filesystem it is using. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can boot from a live usb (with Linux on it) and copy the files

Comment: @MaxSilvester Boot from live usb connect my harddisk, do i have to use something else to copy paste data? And just to be sure I can use live usb without harddisk in my pc right?

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox You can boot from the live usb without a Harddisk. You only need a harddisk if you want to install something.

Comment: The point to my last comment was windows will assume a `mount` will be NTFS or FAT32 (which is not a default for a Ubuntu *file-system* thus you'll need to provide details).  I too would use a *live* file system, such as Ubuntu install media as your hdd/ssd will be a native and thus `mount` will be far easier. You only need another drive/device if that's where you're going to copy files to, normally I `mount` network storage (NFS) & `cp` (copy) my files there so don't bother with other hdd/ssd on box being used. A *live* system if a Ubuntu release is also on-topic here :)

Comment: @guvierc & @ MaxSilvester Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me:-**

1.Take out the internal harddrive and use sata cable or case to connect it to other pc
2. Other pc should be running ubuntu or you can use vm to run ubuntu on it
3. Connect your internal harddrive and copy the data to the desired storage system